# automatically Generate unique id for characters mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to create a mysql table with three columns id , name, name_id,

The thing that i want to acheive is whenever user enters a name into database
then system should generate a unique id for name automatically.

e.g. 
name is JJ then name_id should be 1 and if name is  DD then name_id should be 2 
also if name JJ is repeated in database then name_id should be 1.

The number_id values should be assign according to name sorting 
i.e **A** should get 1 and  **B** should get 2.

How this can be achieved by sql script or triggers ?

Comment: @Prix: that won't fulfill his last requirement. Although I can't really see much use for that last requirement. @user2614607: If `A` should be `1` and `B` should be `2`, what should `user2614607` get? Is this determined somehow?

Comment: It means that id should be assigned according to Alphabetical Arrangement of names. e.g. ABC should get 1 and CBA get value 2 and so on

Comment: @user2614607 yes, but unless you batch add every name at once, your name_id field can't possibly continue to keep those numbers in order, unless it's replacing the value on all the items after it when a new one is added in the middle...  why couldn't you use a sort on the names and figure out their position in the record set dynamically instead of storing that value?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
INSERT INTO tbl (name,name_id) 
SELECT newname, COALESCE((SELECT name_id FROM tbl WHERE name=newname ),
                         (SELECT max(name_id)+1 FROM tbl))
```

This is assuming that column `id` takes care of itself, i.e. is `auto_increment`ed.

`newname` can of course also be a string constant which you will have to work in to your command.

The command above works best when used for indiviual inserts ("by a user"). If you want to carry out a bulk import then it can be quite costly since for each new value the table `tbl` will be scanned twice. For this case a different logic should be applied:

First find all `name`-`name_id` pairs by means of a `group`ed select and then `INNER JOIN` the results with the import list. For the remaining items (without existing `name_id`s) do the following: find out the highest `@i=max(name_id)` of all records and then import the  *sorted* list with an autonumbering mechanism (`@i:=@i+1`) for `name_id` in place ...

Answer (score 0):

create a sql function that returns the name
_id upon passing name as a parameter.  one way would be to add all the characters but that wont do because different arrangement of same characters would give the same sum for different names.may be concatenating primary index at the end of sum would do the job. i think you can define a suitable logic in a sql function to achieve the results.

Comment: your answer makes sense for me. but can you please clarify when a user will enter name the system should persist the name_id into database at rumtime.

Comment: i am not sure what interface will you provide to your user of if you yourself will be the user. in either case, you will have to create a function lets say function name_to_id('name','the auto increment index) and it returns name_id which is sum of all characters concatenated with its index. then, insert into table(col1,col2,col3) values (value 1,value2, name_to_id(value1,value2);
this might work